# Can Cortana launch a website in a web browser

Tags: cortana

As We know, When Cortana does not a have well defined answer for a query or voice commands she launches bing in edge browser(in windows 10 PC).So I guess Cortana is able to launch bing in a web browser.

Now my question is,
is it possible to launch any website say **www.xyz.com** in a web browser(chrome,edge etc.) using Cortana voice command.
  **Use Case**

**I to Cortana**: launch www.xyz.com
**Cortana in Response**: launches home page of www.xyz.com in my default browser.

Now Supoose www.xyz.com has three page Home,About and Contact us
**I to Cortana**: navigate to About Page
**Cortana in Response**: navigates me to the About page of the site.

Is this possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but it is not exactly supported by Cortana.

1. Create a shortcut for the link you want to go to.
2. Name it xyz.com about page
3. Move the shortcut in the Folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
4. I would recommend creating a folder in that folder otherwise it will quickly clutter your program list.

Then you can say Cortana start/ open xyz about.

Note: it will only work for xyz.com